# I am getting AnonymousUser for request.user after loggin out in Django. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a view called `LogoutView` that is decorated with the `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])` decorator. When I call the `get()` method on this view, I am getting `AnonymousUser` for `request.user` after logging out.

I have tried the following things to fix this, but none of them have worked:

1. I have checked the request.user.is_authenticated attribute to make sure that the user is authenticated before logging them out.
2. I have returned a 401 Unauthorized response if the user is not authenticated.
3. I have called the `logout()` method to log the user out.

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from myapp.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
import requests

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from .models import ChatRoom, UserChatRoom
from myapp.serializers import ChatRoomSerializer, UserSerializer

from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
import requests

from .models import User  # Make sure you import your User model correctly
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny


class GoogleLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        credential = request.data.get('credential')

        google_response = requests.get(f'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={credential}')
        if google_response.status_code == 200:
            google_data = google_response.json()
            email = google_data.get('email')
            name = google_data.get('name')
            photo_url = google_data.get('picture')

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                user.google_credential = credential
                user.save()
                user = authenticate(request, google_credential=credential)
                login(request, user)
                request.session['email'] = user.email
                print(request.user, "authenticated")
                print("Session Data:")
                for key, value in request.session.items():
                    print(f"{key}: {value}")
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create(email=email, google_credential=credential, name=name, photo_url=photo_url)
                user = authenticate(request, google_credential=credential)
                login(request, user)
                print(request.user, "authenticated")

            user_data = {
                'email': user.email,
                'name': user.name,
                'photo_url': user.photo_url,
                'session_data': request.session,
            }
            print(user_data)

            return Response({'success': True, 'user': user_data})

        return Response({'success': False}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create_chat_room(request):
    serializer = ChatRoomSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        chat_room = serializer.save()
        user_chat_room = UserChatRoom.objects.create(user=request.user, chat_room=chat_room)
        return JsonResponse({'room_id': chat_room.id})
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def list_chat_rooms(request):
    chat_rooms = ChatRoom.objects.all()
    serializer = ChatRoomSerializer(chat_rooms, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


class LogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def get(self, request):
        print(request.user, "logging out")
        logout(request)
        print("success")
        return Response({'success': True})


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def all_user_list(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide in fixing this issue.

````py
from pathlib import Path 
  
 # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'. 
 BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent 
  
  
 # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production 
 # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/ 
  
 # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret! 
 SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-**3#3)l+^f%&u*wk3u$&duz@**5a7b8+c*%do!&!v7emzt_$vn' 
  
 # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! 
 DEBUG = True 
  
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] 
  
  
 # Application definition 
  
 INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
     'daphne', 
     'django.contrib.admin', 
     'django.contrib.auth', 
     'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
     'django.contrib.sessions', 
     'django.contrib.messages', 
     'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
     'myproject', 
     'myapp', 
     'corsheaders', 
  
 ] 
  
 MIDDLEWARE = [ 
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
     'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
 ] 
  
 ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls' 
  
 CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ 
     "http://localhost:3000",   
 ] 
 SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache" 
  
 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [ 
     'myapp.backends.GoogleOAuthBackend',   
     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
 ] 
  
 TEMPLATES = [ 
     { 
         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 
         'DIRS': [], 
         'APP_DIRS': True, 
         'OPTIONS': { 
             'context_processors': [ 
                 'django.template.context_processors.debug', 
                 'django.template.context_processors.request', 
                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 
                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 
             ], 
         }, 
     }, 
 ] 
  
 WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application' 
 ASGI_APPLICATION = "myproject.asgi.application" 
  
 CHANNEL_LAYERS = { 
     "default": { 
         "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer", 
         "CONFIG": { 
             "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)], 
         }, 
     }, 
 } 
  
 DATABASES = { 
     'default': { 
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3', 
     } 
 } 
  
  
 # Password validation 
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators 
  
 AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [ 
     { 
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator', 
     }, 
     { 
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator', 
     }, 
     { 
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator', 
     }, 
     { 
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator', 
     }, 
 ] 
  
  
 # Internationalization 
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/ 
  
 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' 
  
 TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' 
  
 USE_I18N = True 
  
 USE_TZ = True 
  
  
 # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images) 
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/ 
  
 STATIC_URL = 'static/' 
  
 # Default primary key field type 
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field 
  
 DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField' 
  
 SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"  
 # SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache" 
 # SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False   
 # SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False   
  
  
 # CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True```


I would appreciate any help you can provide in fixing this issue.
````

Comment: What is your [`DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` setting](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme)? -- also in the code you provided, the `LogoutView` class does not specify `permission_classes`, despite the fact that your question says that you decorated this with `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])` -- so I'm not sure if that's a transposition issue when writing the question or an error in the question or code.

Comment: I have updated my code but is not working I added premission_classes([isAuthenticated]) But still I'm getting in output as ```AnonymousUser logging out 
```